# Control freeze in chart while painting?

Tags: vb.net, charts, paint, freeze

I have a Windows Form Application with, among other things, about a dozen text boxes and a Chart control. Modifying any of the `textbox` fires a subroutine that updates the data in the Chart control.

In the chart control there are 5 series.  By adding tracking statements in the various events of the chart and my subroutines I have discovered that the the subroutines that update the chart data finish but the application freezes between the `PrePaint` event and `PostPaint` event for the 3rd series of the chart.

If left for long enough everything finishes and the application starts working normally again.  Also, this only happens for a certain combination of data and only on one particular computer (a test computer, not my development computer).

I'm looking for any suggestions or hints as to why this happens.

Comment: You shoul consider running the update routine asynchronously

Comment: ^ What he said.  Run it in another thread.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, I am new to VB.net and still learning.  I update the chart by adding points to the series.  This means interacting directly with the control on the main form.  It was my understanding that this can only be done from the main thread.  If I use Invoke to start the update routine in the main thread from another thread, isn't the main thread still performing the update?